# PhpStorm: Local History displays no file content (empty), but the list of local history records is displayed

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Local history records are displaying empty.

I use **PhpStorm 2020.1.4** (But seems like the same thing was in 2020.1.2).

The host is **Windows 10**, Project files a stored on **WLS2** (Windows Subsystem for Linux, Ubuntu 20.04)

*Git history works perfectly.

What can be the possible reason and how to fix it?

[image: screenshot of the local history window]

Comment: With  PhpStorm 2020.2 version this bug seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly currently it does not work with `\\wsl$\` kind of paths.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-241935 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

**UPDATE 2020-12-01:** the aforementioned ticket has "Fixed" status now. It should be working since **2020.2.1** version.